# Do I need to turn on VT-x in order to make a virtual machine using Oracle VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, vt-x

Do I really have to turn on VT-x in BIOS to make a virtual machine? I keep
getting the error about VT-x not being turned on but I feel like turning it
on could have a negative impact on my computer. I heard it *can* be a security risk.

Is there any way I can make a VM without using VT-x?

Comment: What OS are you trying to install into the VM?

Comment: Windows 10 32-bit version

Comment: VT-x should only be required if you are attempting to run a 64-bit OS within a VM on a 32-bit OS.

Comment: I have a 64bit system. If I attempt to run the 32bit VM I get the error but I can still turn the VM on. I get this screen https://imgur.com/a/SGx6Wn0   I am stuck at this screen even when I wait for about a hour.

Comment: Also I can't make a 64bit VM since the option for that isn't there. The only fix I could find for that is turning on vt-x..

Comment: @Yokool - Hardware virtualization is required for the option to appear in your current configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can make a VM without using vt-x?

Yes. VT-x is not a *necessity* for running a virtual machine. However without it a software solution is needed, which won't be good in performance

32-bit virtual machines can be run with [binary translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation), which is not much slower than a hardware-assisted solution, but 64-bit VMs can only be run inside an [emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator) (like [qemu](https://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) or [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/)) if VT-x is not available, because [isolation of the virtual machine would be impossible without it](https://superuser.com/q/156859/241386). That's far worse than running native code, maybe even 10 times slower

> I feel like turning it on could have a negative impact on my computer

That's just nonsense. If you don't run a VM then nothing is consumed by the VT-x feature. See [Does disabling VT-x enhance stability/performance?](https://superuser.com/q/651865/241386)

Comment: They are some vulnerabilities that were discovered this year that involves VT-x.  The author’s concern isn’t completely unwarranted, but they can’t have hardware virtualization, without enabling it (which is required to run a 64-bit VM within a 32-bit host)